# Write from Serial to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to write a script that will constantly listen to a serial device and write everything to a file. But its not writing anything to the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
import serial
import time

i = 0

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART', 115200, timeout = 1)

while True:
    readOut = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    file = open("output.txt","w")
    file.write(readOut)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening it as `w` each time, which erases the content. Change to:

```py
import serial
import time

i = 0

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART', 115200, timeout = 1)

while True:
    readOut = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    file = open("output.txt","a")
    file.write(readOut)
    file.close()
```